Kotlin setText unresolved reference to TextView
So the Youtube video I am following along with was uploaded three years ago and since then, Kotlin has changed and synthetic has been deprecated; where the person on the Youtube video used this code:
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_game_screen.*

It no longer works. Instead I have to use something called view binding which is a bit confusing. So what RyuSnow did on this video: https://youtu.be/aeC6nHyMjro?t=641 was he has a .kt file called "Story.kt" and this file defines a function. I guess the synthetic import was very important to get the TextView to set text from this .kt file but it no longer works.
Then he uses another file called GameScreen.kt to call the function from Story.kt; it's a bit frustrating because I cannot simply follow along with the tutorial. What do I do to get the gameTextView to not be red and not say "Unresolved Reference" in Story.kt?
I tried searching for answers but I feel like I'm chasing my tail. None of the answers seem to fit my specific situation.

The approach they're likely using (View Synthetics) has been removed since Kotlin 1.8, with the discontinuation blog post documenting how to migrate over to View Binding as you've mentioned

Synthetics are deprecated and no longer work. For more information about that, see this question.
You need to migrate to view binding. Enable view binding in your project by following the directions in the Setup section here.
Follow the directions in the Use view binding in activities section on that same page to add the bound view to your GameScreen class. So your GameScreen class would look like:
class GameScreen: AppCompatActivity() {

    lateinit var binding: ActivityGameScreenBinding

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityGameScreenBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)
      
        val story = Story(this)
 
        // continue on by following the tutorial
    }
}

In your Story class, you need to get the views from the binding whenever you use them, which can be done by inserting binding. before the view name. For example, instead of
gs.gameTextView.setText("blah blah blah")

you would put
gs.binding.gameTextView.setText("blah blah blah")

And if later in the tutorial they do something with views directly in the GameScreen class, you would also put binding. before the name of any views you're interacting with.

Holy smokes it works. Thank you Tenfour04
